# Proportion of Values

Tags: statistics

I'm not quite sure how to do this problem:

Calculate the the proportion of values that is 3 in the following data set:

2, 3, 3, 6, 9

Answer (score 7):

You have 5 values, and 2 of these are 3. Therefore, the proportion of the data that is 3 is given by
$$\frac{\text{number of 3s}}{\text{number of data}}=\frac{2}{5}$$

Answer (score 4):

The proportion, in general, is **just the ratio of the frequency of a datum you are given to the number of elements in your data. For example**, in the set `1,2,3,3,4`, the proportion of $1$ to the rest of the data is,$${\text{frequency of 1}\over \text{total number of data}} = {1 \over 5}$$Given the above example, can you now perform your question?